# autoapproval with Lightopenid (after inital approval)

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, openid

I am using [LightOpenId](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/) which basically combines `OpenID` and `OAuth1.0`.

The approval works fine, however, my customers need to approve every single time. I would like `OpenID` to realise, that the customer already approved (basically utilizing the checkbox **"remember this approval"**) and go through without showing the approving mask again.

How can this be done?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: in case anyone is looking for an answer, i want to save you the hours it took me:

openid.realm NEEDS to end in '/' for this to work.
Therefore all i changed was line 716 to:
'openid.realm'       => $this->trustRoot.'/',

Answer (score 0):

I have ignored this problem on my application for a while, and almost missed your solution because it was in the comment.

It is possible apply a "fix" in the first part of your handler without actually modifying the LightOpenId code thus:

```
  $mysiteurl = 'https://my.site.url/'; // note trailing '/' included

  $openid = new LightOpenID($mysiteurl); // <- the trailing '/' onwards is stripped internally
  if (!$openid->mode) {
      $openid->required = array(
        'namePerson/first',
        'namePerson/last'
         // etc...
      );
      // redirects to google openid provider
      $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
      $openid->realm = $mysiteurl; // <- ADD THIS LINE - resets realm with the trailing '/'
      header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
      return;

  } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
    header('Location: '. $mysiteurl.'cancelled.php');
    return;

  } elseif (!$openid->validate()) {
    header('Location: '. $mysiteurl.'failed.php');
    return;
  }

  header('Location: '. $mysiteurl.'success.php');
  return;
```